# BGL: bundled object without a default constructor?

Tags: c++, boost

This question is about the `Boost Graph Library`.

Suppose that my graph type is defined like this:

```
using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<vecS, setS, directedS, State>;
```

Now, if I understand correctly, I can add a new `State` object `s` to the graph like this:

```
auto vd = add_vertex(g); // g is a Graph object
g[vd] = s;
```

There are two problems with this way:

- it requires `State` to have a default constructor. In the case of this particular class `State`, a default constructor simply does not make sense.
- This way I pay for the default construction of a `State` object when the vertex is added. This cost is a pure run-time overhead.

So, is there a way to avoid the need for a default constructor for the bundled objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html):

> The types of all property values must be Copy Constructible, Assignable, and Default Constructible. The property maps obtained from the adjacency_list class are models of the Lvalue Property Map concept. If the adjacency_list is const, then the property map is constant, otherwise the property map is mutable.

You should make a property type that is capable of *holding* or *referencing* your `State`.

For the very first step you might have success with the overload that takes the property:

```
auto vd = add_vertex(s, g); // g is a MutablePropertyGraph object
g[vd] = s;
```

See other [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph/doc/MutablePropertyGraph.html)

Comment: Do you still need `g[vd] = s`? Also, is my `Graph` type suitable for use with this overload?

Comment: You could just look out up in the linked documentation. But yes, that should be applicable. The requirements for the property type don't change, though, so consider the systematic shorn instead.